# AWS Amplify Rewrites and redirects Change http -> https

Tags: aws-amplify

It would seem that AWS Amplify - Rewrites and redirects, user interface always changes the destination url from http to https.

Example

```
Source Address: /othersite/<*> 
Destination: http://www.example.com
```

But after you hit save it's been changed to https://www.example.com.
How can one use amplify to proxy to a non https site. I have looking through the "Rewrites and redirects" part of the documentation and don't see any examples, requirements or info on this behavior.

Is this a requirement?
Bug?

Anyone else have info on this, thanks.